# plotting two functions in one 2D graph in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following function (for example):

```
f<-function(x,a,b) a*sinh(x/b)
```

where x is real from -L to L.
Also, a and b, discretely increments from a1 to a2 and from b1 to b2, respectively. (e.g. for loop with some steps)

I'm wondering how I can plot `f_max` (maximum of `f` for -L < x < L ) and `f_avg` (average of f over -L < x < L ) versus `a` both in the same plot for when `b` is also changing. I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

If anything is missing in my question, please make any assumption as you wish (without asking). It should help anyways as my question is general.

**As you may notice I am trying to visualize 2 different 3D graphs (f_max vs a vs b) and (f_avg vs a vs b) in one 2D graph. ggplot2 plus coloring and linear curve fitting is highly appreciated.**

Comment: Appreciate if someone with higher rank make my image visible.

Comment: @nicola I owe you a beer -- thank for making the pic visible :]

Comment: For finding the maximum/minimum value of a function over a range see `?optimize`. For the average, see `?integrate` (and remember the average definition). You need to build a grid of `a` and `b` values (see also `?expand.grid` for this) and for each `a`-`b` combination call `optimize` and `integrate`. Then you get the points that you can add to your plot.

Comment: @nicola Thanks, I'm new to R but will dig more into what you said. Any effort on writing an answer/code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicated, you need to create a grid of values first, but the `optim` and `integrate` suggestions aren't needed for this sort of task.

```
grid.xab <- expand.grid(a = c(4,5,6), 
                        b = c(1,1.5,2), 
                        x = seq(-2, 3, length.out = 50))
```

> ```
>     a   b  x
>   1 4 1.0 -2
>   2 5 1.0 -2
>   3 6 1.0 -2
>   4 4 1.5 -2
>   5 5 1.5 -2
>   6 6 1.5 -2
>          ...
> 445 4 1.5  3
> 446 5 1.5  3
> 447 6 1.5  3
> 448 4 2.0  3
> 449 5 2.0  3
> 450 6 2.0  3
> ```

You see this makes every possible combination of the **a** and **b** values with the range of **x** values. Depending on the precision you need, you can change `length.out =`. Now you evaluate *f*(**x**) at every point.

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

grid.xabf <- grid.xab %>% mutate(fx = a*sinh(x/b))
```

> ```
>   a   b  x         fx
>   1 4 1.0 -2 -14.507442
>   2 5 1.0 -2 -18.134302
>   3 6 1.0 -2 -21.761162
>   4 4 1.5 -2  -7.060142
>   5 5 1.5 -2  -8.825177
>   6 6 1.5 -2 -10.590212
>                     ...
> 445 4 1.5  3  14.507442
> 446 5 1.5  3  18.134302
> 447 6 1.5  3  21.761162
> 448 4 2.0  3   8.517118
> 449 5 2.0  3  10.646397
> 450 6 2.0  3  12.775677
> ```

---

You can visualize this:

```
ggplot(grid.xabf, aes(x, fx)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(a), linetype = factor(b)))
```

[image]

---

Now we just need to collapse all the **x** values to get the maximum and average values of *f*(**x**) for each **a** and **b**.

```
f.hat <- grid.xabf %>% 
  group_by(a, b) %>% 
  summarise(fmax = max(fx), favg = mean(fx))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 4
> # Groups:   a [?]
>       a     b      fmax     favg
>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
> 1     4   1.0 40.071500 5.203415
> 2     4   1.5 14.507442 2.113929
> 3     4   2.0  8.517118 1.307466
> 4     5   1.0 50.089375 6.504269
> 5     5   1.5 18.134302 2.642412
> 6     5   2.0 10.646397 1.634333
> 7     6   1.0 60.107250 7.805122
> 8     6   1.5 21.761162 3.170894
> 9     6   2.0 12.775677 1.961199
> ```

---

And now we can finally make the figure you want:

```
p1 <- ggplot(f.hat) + 
  geom_line(aes(a, fmax, color = factor(b), linetype = "f(x) max")) +
  geom_line(aes(a, favg, color = factor(b), linetype = "f(x) avg")) +
  geom_point(aes(a, fmax, color = factor(b)), shape = 16) +
  geom_point(aes(a, favg, color = factor(b)), shape = 1)

p1
```

[image]

But we can also make it a bit nicer:

```
p1 + 
scale_linetype_manual(values = c("f(x) max" = "solid",
                                   "f(x) avg" = "dashed"),
                        labels = c("f(x) max" = expression(bold(max)~italic(f)(x)), 
                                   "f(x) avg" = expression(bar(italic(f)(x)))),
                        name = expression(widehat(italic(f)(x)))) +
  labs(y = expression(widehat(italic(f)[-2]^3*(x))),
       color = "b",
       title = expression(italic(f)(x)==a%.%bold(sinh)*bgroup("(",frac(x, b),")")))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm still trying to get all you have done. I'll mark it as the answer as soon as perceive it completely. Thanks a lot. Meanwhile, can you please improve the look of the graph? It does not look interesting or beautiful at all. I actually came from Mathematica, Python and MATLAB hoping to obtain more appealing plots in R. THANKS

Comment: @KyleDean, visual aesthetics are very much in the eye of the beholder. `ggplot2` figures are very customizable; I recommend http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/ to learn about some of the options.